# changing a form field within a view to have dynamic attrs

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I have a shopping cart and I don't want customers to be able to add a quantity of product greater than my inventory. my form field for adding to the cart is as follows.

the quantity field is as such:

```
quantity = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 
                                                            'class':'quantity', 'maxlength':'5'}),
                              error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.', 'max_value':'max value error'}, min_value=1)
```

since my form model does not access my database, i cannot use a variable for the max_value attribute.

So in my view, i override this such that after someone has submitted the form, i state:

```
form.fields['quantity'] = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'2', 'value':'1', 
                                                            'class':'quantity', 'maxlength':'5'}),
                              error_messages={'invalid':'Please enter a valid quantity.', 'max_value':'Sorry. We dont have that many in stock.'}, min_value=1, max_value=quantity)
```

where

> max_value=quantity

is the number of items in my inventory. after which i call form.is_valid(). 
Doing this gives me the desired result. 
My questions are whether or not it is OK to do this, and is there a better way?

Comment: I would make an Ajax view which takes a product id (perhaps) and returns the actual status. And when the user adds it to the cart it checks the ajax view if it's possible to add to cart.

Comment: At the views.py it can be bit shorter: `form.fields['quantity'].max_value = quantity`

Comment: Abbasov - I have tried using that form but it seems to have no affect. I don't get any errors or anything either.

Comment: Yeah, `max_value` is only checked during the field's `__init__` method, at which point if you provided a value it will add a `MaxValueValidator` to the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing really wrong with that, but a better way to do it is to modify the field's `validators` attribute rather than toss out the whole definition:

```
form.fields['quantity'].validators.append(validators.MaxValueValidator(quantity))
```

Just changing `max_value` on the field won't do anything, because that value is only checked during the `IntegerField`'s `__init__` method.

You could do this in the form's `__init__` method instead of the view - I'd probably lean that way just to be sure I didn't forget to set it somewhere.

Another perfectly fine way to do it is to check the DB in a custom `clean_quantity` method on the form:

```
def clean_quantity(self):
    available_quantity = # some database lookup
    if self.cleaned_data['quantity'] > available_quantity:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Only %d items are available' % available_quantity)
    return self.cleaned_data['quantity']
```

I think adding in the validator is simpler, personally, but in part it depends on how many views you're planning to use the form in.

Comment: I had been looking for something along the lines of adding a validator but I  couldn't get the syntax right. Thank you everyone for you quick replies. And i'll take a look into Ajax at some point.

Comment: Ajax can be pretty handy but obviously you still have to do the server-side validation - both because the situation could have changed since the Ajax confirmation and because the client input isn't trusted.